# Printer spools but doesn't print

Tags: windows-7, printer, print-spooler

I am having a bizarre issue with an end user who is unable to print to a USB attached printer.

The environment is as Windows 7 machine with a Canon Pixma iP90 printer. The driver is installed (and has been re-installed several times), but whenever a print job is sent the printer spools but no printing ever occurs.

The following is some relevant information

- I can confirm that the printer is spooling as the spool folder fills up, and the job "releases" and the spool folder empties
- I have turned off print spooling with no luck
- None of the features from the Canon utilities (ie Turn Printer Off) features work
- Computer recognizes the printer as being installed. When the cable is unplugged the printer icon grey's out in Devices and Printers
- Printer and cable are confirmed working as they work with other PC's in the office
- I have deleted the USB Root Hub devices and rebooted the machine with no luck
- No error messages are displayed or logged in the event viewer.
- The Canon diagnostics utility doesn't detect any problem and states the printer is functioning properly
- Printer is not shared
- User is able to print to other shared printers in the office

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the attempted print jobs in the que for that printer? If so, you may want to clear them as you troubleshoot. Also, make sure you are using the latest printer drivers from Cannon's site.

Comment: There are no documents in the queue. They show up briefly then disappear with no print job and no error message displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has since been resolved. This is how I did it...

- Uninstalled ALL printers (network printers included)
- Unplugged the device
- Stopped the Spooler service and deleted anything in the spool
- Deleted USB Host controllers
- Rebooted the PC (Host Controllers were automatically created once again)
- Installed the printer driver
- Followed prompts and finished installation

Basically...started over COMPLETELY. Not pretty but it worked.